# Refactoring Specialized Behavior from Common Code in Scheme

Tags: scheme, refactoring

This is a problem I come up against all the time. I have a function that
does something useful, but I want a version that does something slightly
different as well.

For example, a substring search that finds all of the
positions where some substring occurs in another, longer piece of text.

Then I discover a use case that only requires finding the first instance
of the substring, or the last, or the n'th. Is there an idiomatic way to
factor out the different behaviors from the larger body of common code?

For example, here are two substring search functions. One returns the
first match. The other returns all matches. (Please ignore the fact that
this is a poor way to do a substring search.)

```lisp
;; Return the index of the first matching instance of `pattern` in
;; `s`. Returns #f if there is no match.
(define (naive-string-find-first pattern s)
  (let* ((p-len (string-length pattern))
         (limit (- (string-length s) p-len)))
    (let outer ((i 0))
      (if (<= i limit)
          (let inner ((j i)
                      (k 0))
            (if (< k p-len)
                (if (char=? (string-ref s j) (string-ref pattern k))
                    (inner (+ j 1) (+ k 1))
                    (outer (+ i 1)))
                i))
          #f))))

;; Return a list of all positions in `s` where `pattern` occurs.
;; Returns '() if there is no match.
(define (naive-string-find-all pattern s)
  (let* ((p-len (string-length pattern))
         (limit (- (string-length s) p-len)))
    (let outer ((i 0))
      (if (<= i limit)
          (let inner ((j i)
                      (k 0))
            (if (< k p-len)
                (if (char=? (string-ref s j) (string-ref pattern k))
                    (inner (+ j 1) (+ k 1))
                    (outer (+ i 1)))
                (cons i (outer (+ i 1)))))
          '()))))
```

As you can see, they are almost identical, differing only in the last
two lines. Specifically, one of those lines handles proceeding from a match.
The other handles proceeding from a failure to match anything.

What I would like to be able to do is something like:

```lisp
(define (naive-string-find-common pattern s match-func fail-func)
  (let* ((p-len (string-length pattern))
         (limit (- (string-length s) p-len)))
    (let outer ((i 0))
      (if (<= i limit)
          (let inner ((j i)
                      (k 0))
            (if (< k p-len)
                (if (char=? (string-ref s j) (string-ref pattern k))
                    (inner (+ j 1) (+ k 1))
                    (outer (+ i 1)))
                (match-func i)))
          (fail-func i)))))

(define (naive-string-find-first-common pattern s)
  (let ((match-f (lambda (x) x))
        (fail-f (lambda (x) #f)))
    (naive-string-find-common pattern s match-f fail-f)))

(define (naive-string-find-all-common pattern s)
  (let ((match-f (lambda (x) (cons x (outer (+ x 1))))) ;; <-- Fails, of course.
        (fail-f (lambda (x) #f)))
    (naive-string-find-common pattern s match-f fail-f)))
```

Handling of the "find-first" behavior works. The "find-all" version
fails because the specialization procedure has no knowledge of the
named let `outer`.

Is there an idiomatic way to factor out the needed functionality in
cases like this?

Comment: Have your `find-first` function take an extra (optional) argument giving the first index to start looking at. Then have `find-all` call it repeatedly until no match is found, updating the start position each time based on the found positions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @soegaard [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74843654/16981884), wrapper functions that add a "flag" argument are idiomatic and clear.

The "What I would like to do" code *could* be repaired, for example (in Racket to use [`check-expect`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/test-engine/index.html#%28form._%28%28lib._test-engine%2Fracket-tests..rkt%29._check-expect%29%29):

```
#lang r6rs
(import (rnrs) (test-engine racket-tests))

(define (naive-string-find-common pattern s match-func fail-func)
  (let* ((p-len (string-length pattern))
         (limit (- (string-length s) p-len)))
    (let outer ((i 0))
      (if (<= i limit)
          (let inner ((j i)
                      (k 0))
            (if (< k p-len)
                (if (char=? (string-ref s j) (string-ref pattern k))
                    (inner (+ j 1) (+ k 1))
                    (outer (+ i 1)))
                (match-func i (lambda () (outer (+ i 1))) )))
          (fail-func i)))))

(define (naive-string-find-first-common pattern s)
  (let ((match-f (lambda (x k) x))
        (fail-f (lambda (x) #f)))
    (naive-string-find-common pattern s match-f fail-f)))

(define (naive-string-find-all-common pattern s)
  (let ((match-f (lambda (x k) (cons x (k))))
        (fail-f (lambda (x) '())))
    (naive-string-find-common pattern s match-f fail-f)))

(check-expect (naive-string-find-first-common "ab" "abab") 0  )
(check-expect (naive-string-find-first-common "ab" "a-b-") #f )

(check-expect (naive-string-find-all-common   "ab" "abab") '(0 2) )
(check-expect (naive-string-find-all-common   "ab" "a-b-") '()    )

(test)
```

Comment: Thank you. I prefer this solution since there is no need to keep adding additional `if` s or `cond` clauses to the base procedure for each new use case.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an idiomatic way to factor out the needed functionality in cases like this?

The way you have done is idiomatic.

If two functions `f` and `g` do almost the same work, then make a funktion `h` that can do both. Make `h` take an extra argument, that indicates whether it should behave as `f` or `g` (here a flag that indicates whether to continue after the first needle is found). Finally define "wrappers" `f` and `g` that simply calls `h` with the appropriate flag(s).